# ¿Cómo consumir api rest en java desktop?

Tags: java, json, xml, api, volley

Amigos estoy en una encrucijada, verán tengo un proyecto en java desktop y en el cual me es urgente el poder conectar con un api rest que devuelve en formato json y otra en XML, y pues verán, en android es fácil con volley, pero estoy tratando y no logro hacerlo.

¿Alguien podría ayudarme en demostrar como hacerlo?

Comment: Hola @master_Alcadio. Podrías colocar tu código para ayudar a la comunidad a entender el problema que planteas. Por otro lado, te invito a realizar un [tour] para que ganes tu primera medalla y consultar [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Busca información sobre Java 11 HttpClient o Apache HttpClient.

Answer (score 2):

Como no pones mucha información te pongo unos ejemplos de como obtener datos de un Web Service rest que regresa un XML y otro que regresa un json:

```
public void listarXML(){
        String url="http://localhost:8080/JavaWebServiceServerCRUDRestful/restful/empleados/xml/listarempleados";
        try{
            URL urlObj=new URL(url);
            //abrimos la conexion
            HttpURLConnection conexion=(HttpURLConnection)urlObj.openConnection();
            conexion.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "UTF-8");
            conexion.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conexion.connect();
            //Almacenamos la respuesta
            InputSource resultado=new InputSource(conexion.getInputStream());

            //convertimos la respuesta que viene en binario a un archivo xml
            Document xmlDoc=DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(resultado);
            conexion.disconnect();//desconecto la url

            XPath xpath=XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

            Boolean nodoStatusBool=(Boolean)xpath.evaluate("/collection/empleado",xmlDoc, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);
            if(nodoStatusBool){
                NodeList nodoStatus=(NodeList)xpath.evaluate("/collection/empleado",xmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
                for (int i = 0; i < nodoStatus.getLength(); i++) {
                    Node nodeId=(Node)xpath.evaluate("/collection/empleado["+(i+1)+"]/id",xmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
                    String id=nodeId.getTextContent().toUpperCase();

                    Node nodeNombre=(Node)xpath.evaluate("/collection/empleado["+(i+1)+"]/nombre",xmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
                    String nombre=nodeNombre.getTextContent().toUpperCase();

                    Node nodePuesto=(Node)xpath.evaluate("/collection/empleado["+(i+1)+"]/puesto",xmlDoc, XPathConstants.NODE);
                    String puesto=nodePuesto.getTextContent().toUpperCase();
                    System.out.println("XML-> El id es: "+id+", el nombre es: "+nombre+", el puesto es: "+puesto);
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void listarJson(){
        String urlstr="http://localhost:8080/JavaWebServiceServerCRUDRestful/restful/empleados/json/listarempleados";
        try{
            URL url = new  URL(urlstr);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            JsonReader rdr=Json.createReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
            JsonArray results= rdr.readArray();
            Iterator<?> iterator = results.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) iterator.next();
                System.out.println("JSON-> El id es: "+jsonObject.get("id").toString().toUpperCase()+", el nombre es: "+jsonObject.get("nombre").toString().toUpperCase()+", el puesto es: "+jsonObject.get("puesto").toString().toUpperCase());
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```